# Azure Databricks waiting for cluster to start when cluster is already running

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline that runs few Azure Databricks Notebooks every day. I keep having this problem that the notebook instance keeps running for a long time. When I checked, I see "Waiting for the cluster to start" in the cell output. But, when I checked the cluster, its in a running state. I thought this might be temporary and waited for another 30 minutes and it the cell output was still "Waiting for the cluster to start". Is there a way to force re-check cluster status inside the notebook? if Not, what's the correct way to handle this error

Comment: it looks like a bug, I've seen that. It makes sense to report it to Microsoft support

Comment: Thank you @AlexOtt. But, do you happen to know a workaround?

Comment: I've seen such things when there were some problems between MS & Databricks, but that was an outage, not the normal situation. After outage finished, everything returned to a norm

Comment: I see.. Thanks for the input. I probably think its because of several collect calls i do in my code. I just found that while the cell was executing.. i see several nodes scaling up and down. I need to find out how the scaling works. \

Comment: Pipeline restart seems to help

Comment: @EugeneLycenok, Luckily that worked for me too. But,  i can't ask a customer to just rerun the pipeline on production.. :-D